# Jenkins job unable to access an environment variable

Tags: maven, jenkins, environment-variables

1. I have a project that is setup as a job to build in Jenkins.
2. This project has multiple Maven modules.
3. One of the Maven module has a Maven task, which runs a Java program.
4. This Java program requires an environment variable which is available in the system.
5. When I run the Maven build cycle for that module locally in the terminal of the same system, the Java program is able to read the environment variable.
6. However in the Jenkins build, the Maven task fails as it is not being able to access that environment variable.

Is there anything else that I need to make this env variable visible to Jenkins Maven. I have tried restarting Jenkins after setting the env var, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you please post your stack trace?

Comment: What is your operating environment - Linux, Windows, or OSX?

Comment: Have you checked _Manage Jenkins_ → _System Information_ → _Environment Variables_ already?